# How do I write a ruby method combining keyword arguments with hash?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, keyword-argument

I am trying to design an api that works like this:

```
client.entries(content_type: 'shirts', { some: 'query', other: 'more', limit: 5 })
```

So I have this method in my `client` class:

```
def entries(content_type:, query={})
  puts query
end
```

But I get `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER`

I also tried splatting:

```
def entries(content_type:, **query)
  puts query
end
```

But I get

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>...ry', other: 'more', limit: 5 })
```

What's the right way to do this without switching around the order of the arguments. The second argument has to be a hash and I don't want to use a `keyword argument` as a second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second works in current MRI and JRuby:

```
def entries(content_type:, **query)
  puts query
end
entries(content_type: 3, baz: 4)
# => {:baz=>4}
```

The first one can't work because you can't both have keyword arguments and also automatically collect key-value pairs into a hash argument.

EDIT in response to comment:

If you wanted to pass a hash and not collect extra keywords into a hash, then you need to reverse the signature:

```
def entries(query={}, content_type:)
  puts query
end
entries(content_type: 3)
# => {}
entries({ baz: 4 }, content_type: 3)
# => {:baz=>4}
```

Or, you can splat your hash:

```
def entries(content_type:, **query)
  puts query
end
entries(content_type: 3, **{baz: 4})
# => {:baz=>4}
```

Or, you can make the second argument also into a keyword:

```
def entries(content_type:, query: {})
  puts query
end
entries(content_type: 3)
# => {}
entries(content_type: 3, query: {baz: 4})
# => {:baz=>4}
```

Comment: yeah close enough but doesn't match exactly the api I want. I want to the user to pass in an explicit hash

Comment: nope - can't do that. Without the first argument, the second one is meaningless

Comment: splatting the hash in a method call - wow didn't know that! But that's too much to ask from an api user. I think I will redesign the call